# Parsing Wikipedia Dump Text

Tags: c#, regex, xml, wikipedia

```
{{Infobox Biographie2|charte=linguiste
|région                  = Linguiste occidental
|idées remarquables      = [[épithète homérique]]
|œuvres principales      = * ''Introduction à l'étude comparative des langues indo-européennes'' ([[1903]])
* ''Aperçu d'une histoire de la langue grecque'' ([[1913]])
* ''Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue latine'' ([[1932]])
}}

'''Paul Jules Antoine Meillet''', né le {{Date de naissance|11|novembre|1866}} à [[Moulins (Allier)|Moulins]] ([[Allier (département)|Allier]]) et mort le {{Date de décès|21|septembre|1936}} à [[Châteaumeillant]] ([[Cher (département)|Cher]]), est le principal [[liste de linguistes|linguiste]] français des premières décennies du {{XXe siècle}}. Il est aussi [[philologue]].

== Biographie ==
D'origine bourbonnaise, fils d'un [[notaire]] de [[Châteaumeillant]] ([[Cher (département)|Cher]]), Antoine Meillet fait ses études secondaires au [[lycée Théodore-de-Banville|lycée]] de [[Moulins (Allier)|Moulins]].
```

Here is an exemple of Wikipedia page.
Is there an efficiant way to (in one RegEx):

- Get only the 1st sentence (from Paul to philologue).
- Get only the second value in [[]]. exemple for [[Moulins (Allier)|Moulins]], only taking Moulins.
- Get the proper birth date and death date. exemple {{Date de décès|21|septembre|1936}}, only 21 septembre 1936.
- Remove '''.

```
text = text.Replace("'''", "");
text = text.Replace("|", " ");
text = text.Replace("{{", "");
text = text.Replace("}}", "");
text = text.Replace("[[", "");
text = text.Replace("]]", "");
text = text.Replace("Date de naissance", "");
text = text.Replace("Date de décès", "");

text = RemoveBetween(text, "(", ")");
text = text.Replace("(", "");
text = text.Replace(")", "");
```

What i tried is using .Replace() but of course it's not the result i except.

Comment: You should never use REGEX on XML.  Regex is for regular expressions and XML is not regular.

Answer (score 2):

If you use regex, chances are that you will build something complicated, prone to bugs and hard to maintain.

You can have a look at this page to get a list of existing parsers of such content, to use them or get inspired to build your own:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers

Answer (score 0):

***This can't be done with 1 regex, and shouldn't be done with regex at all, but here you go:***

```
sentence_reg = '(?<=})(?:\s*\'\'\')(.*)'
second_reg = '(?<=\|)\w*(?=])'
date_reg = '(?<=\|)\d*\|\w*\|\d*'
```

***Use them like this:***

```
sentence = re.findall(sentence_reg, text)

second = re.findall(second_reg, str(sentence))

date = re.findall(date_reg, str(sentence))
```

***And printing them like this:***

```
print(sentence[0].replace("'''", '')) # Displays sentence

print(second) # Displays list of all the second values

print(date[0].replace('|', ' ')) # Birth date

print(date[1].replace('|', ' ')) # Death date
```

***Will display this:***

```
Paul Jules Antoine Meillet, né le {{Date de naissance|11|novembre|1866}} à [[Moulins (Allier)|Moulins]] ([[Allier (département)|Allier]]) et mort le {{Date de décès|21|septembre|1936}} à [[Châteaumeillant]] ([[Cher (département)|Cher]]), est le principal [[liste de linguistes|linguiste]] français des premières décennies du {{XXe siècle}}. Il est aussi [[philologue]].
['Moulins', 'Allier', 'Cher', 'linguiste']
11 novembre 1866
21 septembre 1936
```